# Django appointment app, i want the user to see only available time slots (not taken by another user)

Tags: django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am coding a Django app for schdeule appointments and i want the user to only see the available timeslots and not all timeslots,

here is my forms.py:

```
YEAR_CHOICES = ['2023','2024','2025']

TIME_CHOICES = (
    ('2am-3am','2am-3am'),
    ('3am-4am','3am-4am'),
    ('4am-5am','4am-5am'),
    ('5am-6am','5am-6am'),
    ('6am-7am','6am-7am'),
    ('7am-8am','7am-8am'),
    ('8am-9am','8am-9am'),
)

class AppointmentForm(forms.Form):
    full_name = forms.CharField(label='Full Name',max_length=40)
    mobile_number = forms.IntegerField(label='Mobile Number')
    email = forms.EmailField(label='Email Address')
    my_day = forms.DateField(label= 'Choose day',widget=forms.SelectDateWidget(years=YEAR_CHOICES))
    my_time = forms.ChoiceField(label='Choose time',choices=TIME_CHOICES)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.full_name} your appointment is scheduled on {self.my_day} at {self.my_time}"
```

and here is my views.py

```
def appointment(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
       form = AppointmentForm(request.POST)

       if form.is_valid():
           print(form.cleaned_data)
           obj = Appointments()
           obj.full_name = form.cleaned_data['full_name']
           obj.mobile_number = form.cleaned_data['mobile_number']
           obj.email = form.cleaned_data['email']
           obj.my_day = form.cleaned_data['my_day']
           obj.my_time = form.cleaned_data['my_time']
           

           data = Appointments.objects.last()
           context = {'object':data}
  
           existing_appointment = Appointments.objects.filter(my_time=obj.my_time,my_day=obj.my_day)
           
           if existing_appointment.exists():
                
                # Handle the case where the appointment already exists
                messages.success(request, "The Selected Time Has Been Reserved Before!")
                return render(request, 'myapp/appointment_exists.html')
           
           else:
                obj.save()

           message = f"Dear {form.cleaned_data['full_name']} \n \n Your appointment is confirmed on {form.cleaned_data['my_day']} at {form.cleaned_data['my_time']} \n \n Looking to see you soon :)"
           recep_email = form.cleaned_data['email']
           send_mail(
               'Your appointment is confirmed!',
               message,
               EMAIL_HOST_USER,
               ['ahmedabouzied@live.com',recep_email]
           )
            
            
           return render(request,'myapp/appointment_thankyou.html',context) 
    else:
        form = AppointmentForm()
    return render(request,'myapp/appointment.html',context={'form':form})
```

and here is my models.py

```
YEAR_CHOICES = ['2023','2024','2025']

TIME_CHOICES = [
    (0,'2am-3am'),
    (1,'3am-4am'),
    (3,'4am-5am'),
    (4,'5am-6am'),
    (5,'6am-7am'),
    (6,'7am-8am'),
    (7,'8am-9am'),
]
 
class Appointments(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    mobile_number = models.IntegerField()
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
    my_day = models.DateField(null=True)
    my_time = models.CharField(null=True,max_length=100,choices=TIME_CHOICES)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.full_name} your appointment is schdeuled on {self.my_day} at {self.my_time}, Please check you email"
```

and here is my appointment.html

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

i tried alot of options and failed,I appreciate if anyone can help with this logic, i tried a lot of searching but i failed to find an answer for my question

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use a `ModelForm`?

Comment: whats the difference? still i will need the logic, right?